# How do I replace a specific element in a list

Tags: c#, replace

Let's say I want to replace the element `IOES` with the element `Android`.

```
string input = "IOES Windows Linux";
List<string> os = input.Split(" ").ToList();
```

How do I do it?

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\bIOES\b", "Android");` if you want to replace whole word in `input`

Comment: There are multiple ways, two are `String.Replace` and `Regex.Replace`. [system.string.replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0) and [system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Find its index (`List<T>.FindIndex`) and then assign it a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace *whole words* only (say `IOS`, but not `BIOS`) you can try *regular expressions*:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "\bIOES\b", "Android");
```

In *general case*, you may want to *escape* some characters:

```
string toFind = "IOES";
strung toSet = "Android";

string result = Regex.Replace(
  input, 
  @"\b" + Regex.Escape(toFind) + @"\b", 
  toSet);
```

If you insist on `List<string>` you can use *Linq*:

```
List<string> os = input
  .Split(' ')
  .Select(item => item == "IOES" ? "Android" : item)
  .ToList();

...

string result = string.Join(" ", os);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. One I'd consider is to create a simple transformation like this:

```
string input = "IOES Windows Linux";
List<string> os = input.Split(" ")
    .Select(os => os switch { 
        "IOES" => "Android", 
        _ => os 
        })
    .ToList();
```